# how to install different python version in docker container

Tags: python, docker, pyspark

I installed `gettyimages/spark` `docker` image and `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` inside my machine.

However as the `gettyimage/spark` python version is `3.5.3` while `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` python version is `3.7`, the following error come out:

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.5 than that in
>   driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please
>   check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
>   are correctly set.

So, i have tried to upgrade the python version of `gettyimage/spark` image OR downgrade the python version of `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` docker image to fix it.

- Lets talk about method 1, downgrade `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` python version first:

I use `conda install python=3.5` to downgrade the python version of  `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` docker image. However, after i do so , my `jupyter` notebook cannot connect to any single `ipynb` and the kernel seems dead. Also, when i type `conda` again, it shows me `conda command not found`, but python terminal work well

I have compare the sys.path before the downgrade and after it

> ['', '/usr/local/spark/python',
>   '/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python35.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.5',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>
> ['', '/usr/local/spark/python',
>   '/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

I think more or less, it is correct. So why i cannot use my `jupyter` notebook to connect to the kennel?

- So i use another method, i tried upgrade the `gettyimage/spark` image

> sudo docker run -it gettyimages/spark:2.4.1-hadoop-3.0 apt-get install
>   python3.7.3 ; python3 -v

However, I find that even i do so, i cannot run the spark well.

I am not quite sure what to do. May you share with me how to modify the docker images internal package version

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by installing docker images? You pull a docker image so it is added to your docker system, and then spin up a container using the image. There is no installation that occurs. Hence, in this case, `gettyimages/spark` and `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` would be two different images that should not interact with each other unless you are setting up a connection between them through a docker network.

Comment: see this https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/151#issuecomment-296395760 and this https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/603

Comment: @Abhineet Gupta , i use port mapping method to enable the image container connect to the host. And these two image connect to each other through the host.
What i mean of installing docker images is exactly what you said "pull a docker image so it is added to docker system, and then spin up a container using the image". And what i want is modify that image container and update the python version. By default, such notebook image has python 3.7 and python 2.7 only, while i wanna add python 3.5 version.

Comment: @LinPy, Thanks for your comment. However, by default, such python version is not inside the image. So, even i set the environment variable, is still fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I look at the Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/Dockerfile), it installs `python3` which by default is installing python 3.5 for `debian:stretch`. You can instead install python 3.7 by editing the Dockerfile and building it yourself. In your Dockerfile, remove lines 19-25 and replace line 1 with the following, and then build the image locally.

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch
```

If you are not familiar with building your own image, download the `Dockerfile` and keep it in its own standalone directory. Then after `cd` into the directory, run the command below . You may want to first remove the already downloaded image. After this you should be able to run other docker commands the same way as if you had pulled the image from docker hub.

```
docker build -t gettyimages/spark .
```